# getting index out of bounds when the array is not empty

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, debugging

I am producing a card game and one of my deck methods look like this

```
public Cards getCardFromDeck() {

    if (arrayOfCards.get(0) == null) {
        makeDeck();
        shuffleDeck();
    }

    Cards topOfTheDeck = arrayOfCards.get(0);
    arrayOfCards.remove(0);


    return topOfTheDeck;
}
```

`arrayOfCards` is a linked list which I filled with 52 cards.

Now the problem is that this works perfectly fine when I call `getCardFromDeck` in the main method.

But when I try to access it through another class
which I have a method looking like below

```
public void addToHand() {
    hand.add(deck.getCardFromDeck());
}
```

I get Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

which I think it is saying that the array is empty.

Why is this???

array is filled when I access it from deck class which is where the method is but not when I access from player class

below is my whole deck class

```
package com.jc.blackjack;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Deck {

    private List<Cards> arrayOfCards = new LinkedList<>();

    public void makeDeck() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                Cards card = new Cards(i, j);
                arrayOfCards.add(card);
            }
        }
    }

    public void callDeck() {
        for (Cards arbCards : arrayOfCards) {
            System.out.println(arbCards);
        }
    }

    public void shuffleDeck() {
        Collections.shuffle(arrayOfCards);
    }    

    public Cards getCardFromDeck() {

        if (arrayOfCards.get(0) == null) {
            makeDeck();
            shuffleDeck();
        }

        Cards topOfTheDeck = arrayOfCards.get(0);
        arrayOfCards.remove(0);


        return topOfTheDeck;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace and all code relevant to `deck`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing if the linked list is empty by asking for the 1st element by calling `get(0)` and testing for null. This will cause an IndexOfOutBoundsException.

If you want to tell if the linked list has no cards, you can ask it for its size:

```
if(arrayOfCards.size() == 0)
```

... or you can call `isEmpty()`:

```
if(arrayOfCards.isEmpty())
```

Comment: yea but I should still be able to call 0 instance of array by going arrayOfCards.get(0); right?

Comment: No, `get(0)` will attempt to read the 1st element. An empty list has no elements therefore the exception will be thrown. Remember that most of Java uses zero-based indexing.

Comment: yea I was just waiting for the time limit!